# Change thumbnail size in Google custom search API result

Tags: thumbnails, google-custom-search

I'm using Google Custom Search API for searching images to display in my website. But the thumbnail images are too small and I could not find a way to control the thumbnail size. Here is a response for my query:

```
{
"kind": "customsearch#result",
"title": "Big Ben Street London United Kingdom Photo Shared By Halsy16 ...",
"htmlTitle": "Big Ben Street \u003cb\u003eLondon United Kingdom\u003c/b\u003e Photo Shared By Halsy16 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
"link": "http://www.fansshare.com/photos/london/big-ben-street-london-united-kingdom-784722294.jpg",
"displayLink": "www.fansshare_com",
"snippet": "Robert Pattinson's new London",
"htmlSnippet": "Robert Pattinson&#39;s new \u003cb\u003eLondon\u003c/b\u003e",
"mime": "image/jpeg",
"image": {
 "contextLink": "http://www.fansshare_com/gallery/photos/10677077/big-ben-street-london-united-kingdom/",
 "height": 640,
 "width": 1024,
 "byteSize": 80611,
 "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSZJRKQ-yIiSt1FCeYdBKLUEft54xHJo095_r9-rN8OrILnOZPnJZvcwNsG",
 "thumbnailHeight": 94,
 "thumbnailWidth": 150
 }
```

Can someone please tell me if there's a way to get a bigger thumbnail? Or are there any alternative ways to display the search results like in Google Image Search?
Thank you very much!

Comment: how are you even getting thumbnails? I only get the image link.  I am using the .net library  rest4net googleconstomsearch

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) since the Image API is deprecated.

There is no way to tell Google to serve a bigger thumbnail size AFAICS, but you have two possible workarounds:

- use the image url as a CSS background-image property to an element of your chosing (for example, a div with class "portrait"), and use background-position:cover to make sure  the image is scaled up or down to cover the whole element screen estate (Here is an [example](http://thatsthespir.it/quote/view/238) : Andy Warhol 's portrait is fetched via Google)
- link to the full image instead of the thumbnail (the `link`query parameter you have in your example) (but that can be hazardous since you'll have to avoid huge and too small images)

Make sure to experiment with the [api Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list) and its parameters.

Comment: What about cors ? I mean, you cant link the full image.